# Correct way to call commit offsets

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am using Spring integration framework, where input channel is **kafka** and output is **jdbc**.

I want to **manually**  commit kafka offsets, only after `jdbcMessageHandler` successfully processed   each kafka message.

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outChannel")
 public MessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler() {
    JdbcMessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler = new JdbcMessageHandler(getDataSource(), getSql());

     jdbcMessageHandler.setPreparedStatementSetter((ps, message) -> {
            Item item = ((Item) message.getPayload());
            ps.setString(1, item.getName());

           Acknowledgment ack = (Acknowledgment) message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT);
            ack.acknowledge();

    } 
    return jdbcMessageHandler;
}


@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {    
     ...
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    ...
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}     

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());                
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
    ...
    return factory;
}
```

I tried , as can be seen above:

```
Acknowledgment ack = (Acknowledgment) message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT);
ack.acknowledge();
```

But it yields unwanted effect:

each kafka   message  can have n - Items, therefore transformer  returns a List of items , so  ack.acknowledge() (which is commit) will be called for each item, n times!

And I want to call commit once only , after all items of the message are handled.

**Update**

After applying the recommended from answer.

I set on

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory

 .setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(1000L, 99L)));
```

I also have

```
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public void onError(ErrorMessage message) {
        
    }
```

What happens: in  JdbcMessageHandler error occurs,

onError is triggered once. no retries, kafka offset committed.

I need to prevent committing offsets.

**Update 2**

The flow:

1)
kafkainput -> PublishSubscribeChannel  , attached to `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` -> `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` -> `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`

also attempted to set  `listener.setErrorHandler(...`

2)

subscribers:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "kafkainput", outputChannel = "aggregator")

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "kafkainput")
```

3. 

aggregator -> PublishSubscribeChannel

subscriber:

```
 `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "aggregator")`
 public FactoryBean<MessageHandler> aggregatorFactoryBean(..
   AggregatorFactoryBean aggregatorFactoryBean =
   aggregatorFactoryBean.setOutputChannel(outputChannel);
```

4. outputChannel -> DirectChannel

subscriber:

```
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outputChannel")
   public MessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler() {
```

The error occurs in jdbc.
Then only `onError(..)` is triggered

**Update 3**

Did a lot of changes,  got rid of aggregator and instead using:

```
=  new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(container, KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode.batch)
kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setBatchMessageConverter(new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(converter()));
kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setErrorChannelName("error");
kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannelName("splitter");
```

set in `KafkaListenerContainerFactory`

```
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(500,10000)));
```

set in `KafkaMessageListenerContainer'

```
.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
```

and I have splitter:

```
 @Splitter(inputChannel = "splitter", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
```

In kafka I put corrupted message ,  so error occurs in splitter (I am throwing `MessagingException`, then `onError' is triggered once only, and kafka offsets are commited!

```
 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "error")
  public void  onError(ErrorMessage message) {
}
```

why its not retrying number of times that it was configured and why does it commits offsets right away?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider to make yourself familiar with `Publish-Subscribe` pattern. For example a `PublishSubscribeChannel` can have a several subscribers to handle the same message. So, along side with your transformer to produce a list of items, you also can have a service activator which would call that `ack.acknowledge()` only once, when all the items in the batch are processed by JDBC channel adapter. But, of course, the input channel of your transformer must be that `PublishSubscribeChannel`. You also may consider to specify an `order` option explicitly for your subscribers to be sure that they are called in a proper order.

Another way is a `RecipientListRouter`.

See docs for more info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-routing.html#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter

and of course an `@Order` annotation JavaDocs.

Comment: I don't need to preserve an order. Yes I thought about adding another service activator subscribed to the channel, but i need somehow to notify it that jdbc adapter was successful. the input channel of transformer is already PublishSubscribeChannel

Comment: You can also use an [ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice) and either commit the offset in the expression, or downstream of the success channel. However, why not just let the listener container in the inbound adapter take care of committing the offset for you? Just set it's `AckMode` to `RECORD` and you don't need to worry about it at all. Manual commits are usually unnecessary.

Comment: Also, the `PublishSubscribeChannel` stops publishing (by default) if a handler fails. See `setIgnoreFailures`; just make sure they are subscribed in the right order.

Comment: Right. The `order` is not about how you process records in the Kafka batch, but how you subscribe into that `PublishSubscribeChannel`. It is really probably better to let the listener container to handle offset commits for you...

Comment: @GaryRussell So Once I set in  `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`, `AckMode`=record, then, if ServiceActivator of outboundChannel (where I write to database) fails on insert, then commit won't happen? and I don't need to do anything else? So simple?

Comment: I see there is still a problem, when there is an error  occurred in message handler (output) the kafka offsets are committed. I don't wan to commit, I want it to keep retrying the operation indefinitely. How to do this?

Comment: With the default configuration (of spring-kafka, since 2.6) the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` will retry 9 times (10 attempts total) with no back off between attempts. You can configure a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with whatever retry/back off configuration you need. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

Comment: Please see Update added to question.

Comment: You have to re-throw exception back to the Kafka listener container. Why do you need that `onError()` at all?

Comment: I do there some other business logic, this why I need `onError()`

Comment: But if exception doesn’t reach a container, no seek an no retry is going to happen...

Comment: Can I have both? to trigger this handler and to rethrow exception?

Comment: True. Just re-throw an exception in the end of your `onError()` method.

Comment: well I tried, `throw new MessageHandlingException(message);`,  but looks like its not propagated to  ListenerContainer ( container  created by factory , concurrency1)

Comment: Well, we need to see more of your configuration . Probably you move messages to a different thread in between

Comment: Why do you need an aggregator if `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` can be configured with a `ListenerMode.batch` ?

Comment: How that happens that something sends an `ErrorMessage` to that `errorChannel`? The `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` doesn't come with some default one, so if you claim that your `onError()` is called somehow, then you have some async hand off configuration. This way even if you re-throw an exception, it indeed won't reach the container back because you loose a thread boundaries.

Comment: I don't have anything that throws an exception , and if I put a break point inside the onError it looks like async call. but error is comming from: error occurred in message handler [bean 'jdbcMessageHandler

Comment: Right. That's the cause of an exception. Now we need to understand who sends to that `errorChannel`? Since you can set a break point, you probably can trace a call stack and see an origin of the `ErrorMessage`. However I can guess it is an `ExecutorChannel` or a `QueueChannel` in the middle of your flow. Aggregator also could turn the rest of flow into  an async if you rely on the `groupTimeout`. Doesn't look like we continue talking about an offset management. It is more about designing Spring Integration flows to satisfy error handling and your requirements...

Comment: Well from thread stcak it hard to understand from where it comes, but somewhere from `MessagePublishingErrorHandler`  handleError, called from `DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable`. anyway I think it's not good idea to reset offsets, I'll better send the problematic messages to other queue and form there to another kafka topic 'errors'

Comment: Right. That `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` comes really from an `ExecutorChannel` or `AbstractPollingEndpoint` for a `QueueChannel`. So, you definitely do a thread shifting in your logic some way...

Comment: One more time: you need to re-throw an exception from your `onError()`.

Comment: did so, by throwing `MessagingException` from `onError()`, but now the retry attempts are unlimited  though I set `new FixedBackOff(500,3)` I even removed  `onError()`

Comment: Probably you need to use `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` instead?

Comment: changed  `setErrorHandler` to `setBatchErrorHandler` and provided  `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` with same `FixedBackOff` got The error handler must be an ErrorHandler, not org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler  sorry for stupid questions

Comment: Set `batchListener = true` on your `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` along side with that `setBatchErrorHandler`. I did such an assumption according your `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode.batch` option.

Comment: i put BP in `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler`
and see `FixedBackOff{interval=0, currentAttempts=10, maxAttempts=9}`

Comment: OK. Sounds like some problem is over there in the `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler`. Is there any way that you can share with us a simple project to reproduce?

Comment: will try,  but maybe  there is Something else: `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler`  is crated twice!    by my code  `FixedBackOff(500,3)`  and bysomething else with `FixedBackOff(0,9)`, when I put BP I see it comes from  new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>`, And `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler.handle` is called on that instance not mine but that with (0,9).

Comment: Right. That's why it is better to have some project from you, so we can debug it and investigate being at the same time on the same page with you.

Comment: minimal project is ready, I can zip and send the sources with pom, please provide details how to share it.

Comment: Good. Let’s see if you can share it via GitHub!

Comment: sent you invite there

Comment: Thank you for the sample! It is still complex because I think JDBC is fully not relevant and instruction is a bit clamcy. Anyway: I see that your `KafkaListenerContainerFactory`  with the `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` is out of use for that `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. That one uses a ` container()` bean which is not supplied with your `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler`. Does it make sense now?

Comment: not really... you may change the code there... and run to reproduce if needed on your system

Comment: That's your system. I can't keep up on my side what are requirements for the environment. And even honestly: I don't have Apache Kafka. I'd like to have a unit test in your project against embedded one. But still: that's probably not relevant: your `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` is out of use because of wrong dependency design.

Comment: container in injected into adapter

Comment: But that container is not based on the options provided into a container factory. The container factory supplied with your `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` is out of use.

Comment: But I thought I am just overriding the default KafkaListenerContainerFactory...

Comment: You do, but that one still is not used in that `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` any way.

Comment: I think I got it, there is a mix, I should either use `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` in annotation `KafkaListener` or to use adapter and inject `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` with all the properties that i need including `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler`

Comment: i updated the code in git,` SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler`  is created once but still I have unlimited retries  `FixedBackOff{interval=500, currentAttempts=280, maxAttempts=3}`

Comment: Have no idea why is that. I see a mix of versions in your Pom: better to rely on versions managed by Spring Boot

Comment: removed all versions from pom same issue.